# C/C++ - implementing http protocol for PUT request

Tags: c++, c, sockets, http, tcp

I'm writing a http server and I just had question about how to implement a PUT request.

I am reading a client socket one byte at a time, until I reach a CRLF "\r\n" new line, where I send the line to a parser to be tokenized.  When I get two line breaks in a row, I send a response (as it is the http standard to symbolize that the request is finished).

This was fine for implementing GET/HEAD/DELETE.  But now I see PUT has the double line break for the content.

```
PUT /index.html HTTP/1.0
Headers: stuff             <--- not the real CRLF 1
                           <--- not the real CRLF 2
html content goes here     <--- CRLF 1
                           <--- CRLF 2 ... done, send response
```

That is easy enough to account for. If the first line I parse is PUT, I will just say okay, don't send a request until we get the 2nd CRLF1+2.

But what if the content has line breaks too, then how can I know when the client is -really- done sending me stuff?

Answer (score 2):

The client should send a `content-length` header field. For a more in depth discussion, see [RFC 2616 section 4.4 Message length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4).